# I got this selenium exception : Method has not yet been implemented while trying to run my tests using java and Appium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, appium

I got this selenium exception :

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException : Method has not yet been implemented
```

while trying to run my tests using java and Appium and specially this error appear when i try to use `touchAction` and `Tap()`  shall i add some jar file into the project or what ?

What is the origin of this error ?

[image: Expection]

Here the jars i'm using :

[image]

Here appium log

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is the java  client jar version ur using

Comment: I'm using this version 3.3.0

Comment: touchaction and tap both are appium driver, not selenium webdriver...what driver u are using before tap and touchaction method?

Comment: Of course i'm using appium Driver, but the exception is telling selenium.WebDriver. Is it because of jar ?

Comment: When i run without those methods (touch actions) the test is fine but i need those action because the click into button cannot be done

Comment: Would be much clear after looking at the class imports and the code block which runs into this Exception.

Comment: please provide complete exception that is thrown.

Comment: @muraliseleniumtrainer i have added the full exception

Comment: @nullpointer i have added the logs of appium

Comment: should be a mismatch between appium/selenium driver initialization, can u add the code snip

Comment: I am expecting this is issue with appium. see here https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4529 may be old issue but same one. You can try driver.context("NATIVE_APP"); as in link.

Comment: I'm testing a site on browser it's an hybrid one, is that the cause?

Comment: @Emna : could possibly be if you are missing to switch contexts properly. Also I am still waiting to see the line of code where it failed.

Answer (score 1):

download java client 3.4.1 from here and add this to ur build path

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/3.4.1

Comment: I have already updated all my jar files now, but i still have the same issue, take a look into the appium log. As if the perform touch isn't known ...

Comment: yes you are right, just after you put a comment and ask me i update it and selenium-java also to the latest !

Comment: Web context, i'm testing in safari browser in ipad simulator. It 's coded in Angular JS.

Comment: got the point ... just switch the context to native_app and than perform touch action and tap and after that again switch to webview context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112271/discussion-between-noor-and-emna).